# Image is too big while navigating with Navigation Link

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have encountered a problem with image displaying. I'm navigating to a view with background image and when I do that the entire image is closing the screen. [Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXdSe.jpg). I've tried to use Geometry Reader, but It didn't help. Need your assistance.

```
VStack {


// CONTENT HERE

}
            .background (

                ZStack{
                    Image("lake")
                        .resizable()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .scaledToFill()

                    
//                    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
//                        .ignoresSafeArea()
//                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    
                }
                
            )
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

Comment: NOTE: - Just tested the same thing on different project. Everything works fine. I am very confused

Comment: try  .clipped() 
       .scaleToFit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is too big so it's bleeding out of your view. In order to prevent that you can use `.clipped()` after `.background`. This will "clip" the view to make sure none of its contents are rendered outside of its frame.

Comment: No, it's not working. I still see those part of images outside of NavigationLink

Comment: It's working if you add .clipped() after .background. Thank you)

Comment: @DmitriyKaminskiy if the answer solves your problem, the protocol is to mark it as answered (and usually upvoting) instead of creating your own answer. Thanks!

Comment: He edited his answer, I didn't see it. Sorry) Marked as answered

Answer (score -1):

After implementing your Image, you should use .`frame` to set `height` and `width` to your image.

Example:

```
ZStack{
   Image("lake")
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFill()
      .frame(width: 400, height: 400) //This will make your image square. You can choose the size you want.
}
```

Comment: It does not help, Now it's a square when I need to fill an entire screen and it still bigger then the main view

Comment: Did you try .scaledToFit() method?

Comment: .scaledToFit() helps with the problem that image is bigger then displayed screen, but it does not help with filling the entire screen.